# node server works on local machine but as i uploaded to the server i can't connect while the server listen

Tags: android, node.js

on my local machine (windows) i can simply connect and send/receive message.
this is my server code.

```
var app = require('./lib/express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(33432, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:33432');
});
```

i have uploaded this on my server and successfully run this. 
it prints "listening on *: 33432".
but i can't connect to the server from my browser. please help me with this. thanks

Comment: Is there a firewall on the server by any chance?

Comment: there is no firewall. my server is remote and it is apache

Comment: I tried your code (except I had express installed in the regular directory, and not in a lib directory) and it didn't work, so I changed the port to a port I know works on my server (we opened it previously) and the site loaded just fine. In our case we had an AWS server which automatically blocks most ports.

Comment: i solved it.this problem was with the port which was not open on my apache server

Comment: Cool. Glad I could be of help in a small way.